# How do I find what nuget packages contain the project I want

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget

I'm making a class library that exposes an action filter and will be published with NuGet.  I'm trying to install the following with NuGet:

`System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` in assembly `System.Web.Extensions`.

`System.Web.HttpContextBase` in assembly `System.Web`.

How do I find which NuGet package contains these assemblies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `System.Web.Extensions` and `System.Web` are part of the framework, so there are no nuget packages for them.

Comment: So I can't create a class library?  I have to create an ASP.Net Web Application?

Comment: You can, however it will depend on web libraries.

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to create a NuGet package and you want it to add a reference to System.Web and System.Web.Extensions to the project when it is installed.

For GAC references you do this by adding a frameworkAssembly element to your [.nuspec file](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference). The example below is taken from the NuGet documentation.

```
<frameworkAssemblies>
  <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.ServiceModel" targetFramework="net40" />
  <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Web"  />
</frameworkAssemblies>
```

With the above in your .nuspec file your NuGet package will add a reference to System.ServiceModel and System.Web if they do not already exist in the project.